# Android File Transfer cannot access device storage

Tags: file-transfer, moto-x

I am using a Moto X (2nd Generation). I have a recurring problem that occurs when I plug my phone into my Mac to transfer files (music, etc).

When I plug it in, it is unlocked and on. However, Android File Transfer comes up with a message that says:

`Cannot access device storage`

And I am not able to transfer any files. I tried plugging it in again, locking and unlocking my phone, no luck. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have been able to find is to, with the phone plugged in to the computer and unlocked:

1. [Enable Developer Mode in Settings](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-50-lollipop-basics-how-turn-developer-settings)
2. Go to Developer Options
3. Select USB Configuration
4. Select `MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)`
5. If this doesn't work, select `Charging only`, then select `MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)` again.